# Restless worker (6-letter word)

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I may not be the head 
>   But strong to the bone 
>   I bear the load of my company 
>   I’m rarely found alone

Who am I?

Hint:

> A fundamental principle 
>  A prominent supporter 
>  I have an alias too 
>  That can exist on paper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is

> PILLAR

*I may not be the head*

> That would be the roof of the building.

*But strong to the bone*

> Pillars must be made of resistant materials.

*I bear the load of my company*

> Pillars sustain the weight of their buildings.

*I’m rarely found alone*

> There are usually more than one.

*A fundamental principle*

> Wordplay with the fundament of a building.

*A prominent supporter*

> Again, wordplay: the pillar supports the structure in which it's built.

*I have an alias too
That can exist on paper*

> This refers to "column", a layout used in newspaper to write articles.

Comment: You got it! Could you also briefly touch the hint so I can get your answer accepted?

Comment: rot13(Abg gbb fher nobhg gur ynfg 2 ebjf, znlor "cbfg" nf flabavz bs cvyyne naq ersreevat gb vapbzvat znvy?)

Comment: Not that, but it’s simple. Try again

Comment: rot13(Ner lbh ersreevat gb gur pbyhzaf bs n arjfcncre?)

Comment: That’s correct!

Comment: I must say, today I'm on fire with your riddles :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you the

> [tarsus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsus_(skeleton))?

```
I may not be the head
```

> It's in the foot.

```
But strong to the bone
```

> It's made of bones.

```
I bear the load of my company
```

> It includes the heelbone and talus, which bear a lot of weight.

```
Yet I’m rarely found alone
```

> Most people have two.

Comment: Nice guess (+1), but strong to the bone does not mean the bone itself, and your answer needs rest unlike the clue mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be a

> PILLOW

I may not be the head

> It may not be the head, but it's under the head

But strong to the bone

> A pillow is built to withstand the pressures of your head and neck (bones)

I bear the load of my company

> Very supportive during sleep of the head and neck

Yet I’m rarely found alone

> I mean you could have just one pillow. I have multiple pillows, with many being around the house.

Title

> A pillow does not need to rest, but it helps us rest. and it is 6 letters.

Comment: Nice effort (+1). Technically, the pillow is soft for the bone :) Anytime you are not taking rest, the pillow is in rest.